# Usando o Callable em java executa sequencialmente o código

Tags: java, multithreading, paralelismo

Estou a fazer um servidor em java queria executar determinadas tarefas em paralelo. Tenho uma lista de um determinado tipo quero que 20 threads trate de deterimados elementos da lista.

```
for( Item item : result ) {
    Callable< List< IResult > > callable = new HTMLParser( item ); 
    Future< List< IResult > > future = pool.submit( callable );
    set.add( future );
}

for( Future< List< IResult > >  future : set ) {
    List< IResult > result = future.get( ); // wait for a processor to complete
    if( result != null && !result.isEmpty( ) )
        FResults.addAll( result ); 
    }
}
```

Só que executando esta soluçao, analisando os logs parece me que está a correr as threads de forma sequencial

```
2016-12-06 14:17:02.106 DEBUG 18229 --- [pool-1-thread-5] ......
2016-12-06 14:17:02.106 DEBUG 18229 --- [pool-1-thread-5] ....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.106 DEBUG 18229 --- [pool-1-thread-5] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.106 DEBUG 18229 --- [pool-1-thread-5] .......
2016-12-06 14:17:02.106  INFO 18229 --- [pool-1-thread-5] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.243 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-19] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.243  INFO 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-19] ....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.587 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.587 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] ....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.587 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.587 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] ......
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] .....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] ....
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] ......
2016-12-06 14:17:02.588 DEBUG 18229 --- [ool-1-thread-16] ...
```

Os logs de uam thread aparece sequencialmente todo seguido, não me faz sentido. Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Qual a configuração de `pool`? Poste o código. Além disso é interessante  postar mais informações sobre o `HTMLParser`, incluindo as linhas que logam o resultado abaixo e qualquer coisa que possa estar sincronizando o código. Só olhando as linhas de código que você postou não dá para dizer muito sobre o problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade, faz todo o sentido:

```
List< IResult > result = future.get( ); // wait for a processor to complete
```

Você está chamando `get` em cada `Future`, o qual é blocante, fazendo assim uma execução sequencial uma vez que o próximo `get`só vai ser chamado quando o corrente terminar de executar.

A API de `Future`s te dá o método [isDone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone--), o qual não é blocante e vai retornar true se aquela computação estiver finalizada.

Ao invés de passar os `Callable`s um a um você pode usar [invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
List<Future<Whatever>> futures = pool.invokeAll(callables);
```

Depois iterar sobre as futures chamando `get`quando você souber que ela já completou o processamento:

```
for(Future<List<Whatever>> f : futures) {
    if(f.isDone()) {
        f.get() // aqui você faz a mágica acontecer
    }
}
```

Por fim, você não precisa ficar preso ao loop que verifica `isDone`, você pode verificar periodicamente o resultado.

Comment: No final processamento de todas as threads eu quero retornar a lista que é o merge das listas das thread, com esse ciclo "for" se uma não tiver terminado continua e depois termina. Isto é ignora as que não acabaram... Como faço para esperar por todas acabam e no final faço merge das listas de todas as threads ?

Comment: Essa solução se uma thread nao tiver acabado o seu trabalho no isDone o resultado é descartado...

Comment: Como eu disse, você não precisa ficar preso ao `for`, você vai precisar de uma estratégia diferente. Por exemplo, guardar todas as que não estão completas em uma nova lista, esperar um espaço de tempo e então verificar novamente.